# Is broadFileSystemAccess required in UWP when using FilePicker

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, filepicker

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) broadFileSystemAccess and the accompanied windows setting is required for accessing files in locations other than the default UWP app accessible files.

But when using a FilePicker is this still required?

As the User specifies the file using the FilePicker he should only be able to choose file he has access to, hence my confusion. The docs are unclear to me on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, broadFileSystemAccess declaration is required only if you want your app to have programmatically access to all the file system, in every moment and without having to ask every time.

With the FilePicker, you don’t have to use that declaration, because the user has the full command and knows exactly which files the can access.

Best regards

Comment: To add to this, you MUST use the StorageFile object returned by the FilePicker for all file operations. You cannot reliably use the older .NET System.IO API's or try to call File.FromPath on the results of a FilePicker. Only the StorageFile object itself will give you reliable access to the file.

Comment: How so? because of multiple platforms?